# How to create a tabView like the image

Tags: android

I would like to create a tabView like in the picture.

[image]

the gradient tab is the one i have clicked

but i dont want to be like this for example

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

is that possible to be created from my .xml?any help please?

EDIT: .xml code

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header"   
        android:layout_weight="1"   
             />  

    <ImageButton   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header_btn1"      
        />           

    <ImageButton        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header_btn2"  
        />

    <ImageButton  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header_btn3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the actual "tab" components in Android.  In every project that we originally had tabs, we removed them and just used buttons that looked like tabs, and made everything into its own activity.

I would do something like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#000000">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#68cffa">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#68cffa">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/star"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/highlight"
                    android:id="@+id/star1"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#68cffa">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/star"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/highlight"
                    android:id="@+id/star2"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#68cffa">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/star"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/highlight"
                    android:id="@+id/star3"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Make the star image the width/height you want for the whole blue block, and leave the area around the star transparent.  Show/hide the highlight images based on which tab you're currently in.

Comment: thanks mate.i have done the same but i wanted to be sure that this is a trusted way!thanks

Comment: just one more question please.in my app,the "hello" text from the first tab is hiden in the middle and i only see "hel".how can i fix it?i post in the answer above my .xml code

Comment: That first image button will stretch to fill the space with 'layout_weight'.  You really don't want that.  You want an outer layout to contain the image, float the image inside it, and let the layout stretch.  That's why there's an extra LinearLayout in my code and the TextView inside it (it seems like you're using an ImageView instead of a TextView for hello, but same principle).